# Piping md5sum output to grep, but grep is highlighting matches instead of removing non-matches

Tags: centos, pipe

I have downloaded multiple files from a [repo](ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gencode/Gencode_human/release_27/) with many more files. The md5sum information for each file is stored within a single file called `MD5SUMS`.

To check file integrity I did `md5sum -c MD5SUMS` that generated a long output for all of the files in the `MD5SUMS` file, complaining when file not found (I did not download) and saying "OK" when the file is found and md5sum info is matching.

```
md5sum: gencode.v27.tRNAs.gtf.gz: No such file or directory
gencode.v27.tRNAs.gtf.gz: FAILED open or read
md5sum: GRCh38.p10.genome.fa.gz: No such file or directory
GRCh38.p10.genome.fa.gz: FAILED open or read
GRCh38.primary_assembly.genome.fa.gz: OK
md5sum: _README.TXT: No such file or directory
_README.TXT: FAILED open or read
```

I have piped this out to `grep` to filter out "non-OK" lines with `md5sum -c MD5SUMS | grep OK` however <s>I still got the full output</s> I am getting a long output: lines with "No such file or directory" for non-existing files and "OK" phrases being highlighted in red for md5sum matched files.

```
md5sum: gencode.v27.polyAs.gff3.gz: No such file or directory
md5sum: gencode.v27.polyAs.gtf.gz: No such file or directory
gencode.v27.primary_assembly.annotation.gff3.gz: OK
md5sum: gencode.v27.transcripts.fa.gz: No such file or directory
md5sum: gencode.v27.primary_assembly.annotation.gtf.gz: OK
```

However, when I use an intermediate file to store the `md5sum` output and then `grep` that file, I end up with lines including the phrase "OK" as expected.

```
md5sum -c MD5SUMS > test
grep "OK" test

gencode.v27.primary_assembly.annotation.gff3.gz: OK
gencode.v27.primary_assembly.annotation.gtf.gz: OK
GRCh38.primary_assembly.genome.fa.gz: OK
```

I cannot wrap my head around this, can you please help me figure out what is going with wrong with piping or is it expected behaviour?

Comment: Thank you @sudodus for your suggestion. I get the same result if I run the command with `LANG=C`. And I have edited my question as the output is slightly different than described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing error messages produced by `md5sum` for missing files.  These messages are produced on the standard error stream, and since it's only ever the standard *output* stream that is passed across pipes, the error messages won't be affected by the `grep` command at all.

To redirect them away so that you don't see them at all, use

```
md5sum -c MD5SUMS 2>/dev/null | grep OK
```

If you want to save the errors to a log file (to later inspect what files were missing, for example), replace `/dev/null` with the name of a file to write them to.

---

Explanation of the `2>/dev/null` bit:

A command produces output on potentially two separate streams, the *standard output stream* and the *standard error stream*.  These are assigned to "file descriptors" 1 and 2, always.

The standard output stream is where "ordinary output" from the command goes to, and this may be piped to other commands, as in your example where you pipe into `grep`.

The standard error stream is where "diagnostic messages" goes to (this often means "errors"), and this can *not* be piped to another command and usually goes straight to the terminal. This is why your `grep` command seems to fail to filter out the error messages; in fact, it never even sees them.

With `2>` you redirect the standard error stream to someplace else, so that whatever is produced on it will not end up on the terminal.

The equivalent thing for redirecting the standard output stream is `1>`, which may be shortened to just `>`.

The `/dev/null` file is special. Everything that is written to it disappears, completely.

Using `2>/dev/null` after a command means that all error messages are redirected to `/dev/null` instead of to the terminal, and are therefore discarded.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda, your suggestion works and I think I understand the rationale behind but do you mind explaining the `2>/dev/null` part a bit?

Comment: @haci See update.